# Raising an event when button clicked and subscribing it to eventhandler in another class?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I have a form.cs which contains a button and a texbtox, and also a class which handles the event raised when the button is clicked.

basically, when the button is clicked, it should raise an event and the eventHandler in Print class should print text to `TboxPrint` in the form

this is how my code looks like:

```
//Declare the delegate
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //event
    public event EventHandler Print;

    //Event caller, protected to prevent calling from other classes
    protected virtual void OnPrint(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Print != null) Print(this, e);
    }

    //raising event
    public bool print_action(object value)
    {
        OnPrint(EventArgs.Empty);
        return true;
    }

    public void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintClass p = new PrintClass();
        Form1 s = new Form1();

        s.Print += p.printEventHandler;
        print_action(true);
    }
}
```

and the class with method handling the event is:

```
class PrintClass
{
    public void printEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string text = "Print Event occured";
    }
}
```

Apparently nothing is raised.. i believe the way i m raising the event or subscribing to the event handler is wrong. and how i pass the text in eventhandler back to form?

any help is appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need and `extra event subscription` to `Button.Click event`

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        p = new PrintClass();
        button1.Click += cls.printEventHandler;
   }
```

To handle all the buttons on the form you can write a simple snippet like

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        btn.Click += cls.printEventHandler;
    }
}
```

To know which button was clicked you can write `PrintClass` as

```
class PrintClass
{
    public void printEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         Button btn = (Button) sender;
         //btn.Name <-- Control name;
         //btn.Text<-- Control Text;

    }
}
```

---

One thing that I am not understanding is, why do you need a `extra class` if you need to output the result on the same form.

My suggest would be, not to create an `extra class` just for handling all the `Button.Click` event

This can work the way you want : I am removing the need for `extra class`

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            btn.Click += HandleAllButtonClicks;
        }
    }

    private void HandleAllButtonClicks(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button) sender;
        TboxPrint.AppendText(String.Format("Button Clicked : Name = {0}, Text = {1}", btn.Name, btn.Text));
    }
```

Comment: the reason that i need another class is, i have got some data to process, so when the button is clicked, it should notify that class to do the process and return back the output. i hope it is clear

Comment: @Liban - well in that case, the upper half part of the answer would do the job!

Comment: yeah i m doing that..  what about returning the value back to the form (outputing to text box)?

Comment: @Liban - add a field like `internal TextBox outputBox;` to `PrintClass` and access the control!